# How to locate an element with respect to another element identified through innerText using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I've a structure like this:

```
<ul> 
 <div class="someclass"> 
  <li>  
    <img/> 
    <img/>
    <a> <span> Text 1 </span> <a/>
  </li>
  <li>  
    <img/> 
    <img/>
    <a> <span> Text 2 </span> <a/>
  </li>
 </div>
<ul/>
```

I want to search "Text 2" and get back to 1st "`<img />`" of that and I can't proceed further than this `//div[@class='someclass']/li//following-sibling::a/span[text()='Text 2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for the element with text as **`Text 2`** and referencing it to locate the first `<img/>` tag you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based solution:

- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//div[@class='someclass']//li//a/span[normalize-space()='Text 2']//preceding::img[2]"
  ```

Comment: I want to get to <img /> of the list which contains "Text 2".

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Also, I would like to remind that we don't know about which list item contains "Text 2".

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the "Text 2" and then you can use `preceding` with `a[1]` to get the "Text 1".
Your xpath should be like:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Text 2')]//preceding::a[1]
```

Comment: but I need to find the list first without index which contains "Text 2".